# how to mange Alfresco process service development in code repository with versioning

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I am currently working on Alfresco process service 1.8 version. In this I have developed some workflows using Web user interface.

I just wanted to know whether it is a standard process or not, As previously I worked on Alfresco content service and in ACS we are having All-in -one maven project that we used to keep in Git-lab repository after development for managing versioning after new development.

but In case on Alfresco process service we are developing workflow directly using user interface, is there any other standard process that we can use Instead of user interface.

Please suggest the best approach to manage code & development in Alfresco Process service 1.8

Answer (score 0):

[There is a blog post about how to test the models and the code related to them as part of a pipeline](https://community.alfresco.com/community/bpm/blog/2017/10/13/alfresco-process-services-unit-testing-i) - please feel free to give feedback on its suggestions (preferably on the comments section)